# Ignite: problems SELECTing using PHP PDO

Tags: ignite

Accessing the Ignite cluster using PHP PDO.

1) Created a table using a PHP PDO script.

The resulting cache is visible in Ignite Web Console.

SQL SELECTs/INSERTs can be issued from the Ignite Web Console.

SQL INSERTs can be issued using a standalone PHP PDO.

So the SQL table/cache appears to be fully functional, and yet:

2) SELECT from inside a PHP PDO script fails.

The PHP PDO script is essentially the same as the sample script given on the Ignite site.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh=new PDO('odbc:ApacheIgniteDSN');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $res=$dbh->query('SELECT id from Person');
// no errors up to here
//exit;
    if ($res == FALSE)
        print_r("Exception");

    // the following results in errors
    foreach($res as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}*
```

When run from the command line, it generates:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HYC00]: Optional feature not implemented: 0 Specified
>   attribute is not supported. (SQLFetchScroll[0] at
>   ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:543)

This is not very helpful, but on the Ignite node the following is logged:

```
[17:00:30,074][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1314397987, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/100.96.3.26:10805, rmtAddr=/100.96.3.1:6733, createTime=1523811628969, closeTime=0, bytesSent=69, bytesRcvd=75, bytesSent0=69, bytesRcvd0=75, sndSchedTime=1523811629031, lastSndTime=1523811629031, lastRcvTime=1523811629020, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerBufferedParser, directMode=false]], accepted=true]]]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Please note that I created the SQL table using CREATE TABLE command (from a PHP PDO script), rather than explicitly specifying it in the cache using queryEntities.  However, it is seen correctly by the Web Console and you can query against it there, so one would assume that a SELECT from PDO would also work, but it doesn't.

Comment: What is your Ignite version?

Comment: @isapego  2.4.0.  Using kubernetes deployment.          `image: apacheignite/ignite:2.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7362), which is caused by MS cursor library, which is apparently used by the PDO in some cases. It has been fixed and patch has been merged to master as Ignite's Jira states, so you can either wait for 2.5 release, or use master branch code instead.

Comment: I installed a Nightly build from a couple of days ago (2.5.0.20180426), and still exactly the same problem.  It seems that the JIRA issue you mentioned fixes a different ODBC bug.

Comment: @SV, That's weird as I can reproduce your issue on 2.4, but can not reproduce it on 2.5. Are you sure that you have installed everything properly?

Comment: Due to some issues with a relocation of the hosting environment (not related to Ignite), could not re-test this until now.  I have re-installed Ignite cluster from scratch (using 2.5.0 Release), as well as all the Ignite Windows client side libs.  It works perfectly now.  I think I saw that error before with 2.5 beta (after installing 2.4 first) because the Ignite ODBC drivers might've failed to update.  In any case, great work.